# Bind _anonymizeIp() to the asynchronous Google Analytics Snippet

Tags: google-analytics

The German laws require, that user related data must be anonymized before sending to Google. For this, a function called _anonymizeIp() exists and there are some example on the Internet how to use it.

But, my snipped looks different than snippets shown in the examples:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

How to bind _anonymizeIp() here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out. You need to add the following line:

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```